# Python and Windows 10 not releasing file handle

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, visual-studio-code

I've recently upgraded to Windows 10 and now I'm seeing some python code issues.  Here's a simple program that is encountering an issue where Win10 isn't closing or releasing the handle.

```
with open('sample_data.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line)
```

and the error I'm seeing.

```
PS D:\Python>  ${env:DEBUGPY_LAUNCHER_PORT}='50194'; & 'C:\Users\yyy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe' 'c:\Users\yyy\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.3.71659\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\wheels\debugpy\launcher' 'd:\Python\Projects\Delimiter\delimiter_parser.py' 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\yyy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\yyy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\yyy\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.3.71659\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\wheels\debugpy\launcher\__main__.py", line 86, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:\Users\yyy\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.3.71659\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\wheels\debugpy\launcher\__main__.py", line 42, in main
    launcher.connect(launcher_port)
  File "c:\Users\yyy\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.3.71659\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\wheels\debugpy\launcher/../..\debugpy\launcher\__init__.py", line 27, in connect
    sock.connect(("127.0.0.1", launcher_port))
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

Now here's the thing, the FIRST time I run the program all is well, the second time I run it and subsequent times it blows up with the error you see above.. If I wait a few minutes and try again, all is well again (the first time.. )  The time is around 10min or so?

Belg

Comment: Why do you think the file-handle isn't being closed? This looks like a problem with VS Code itself, not your code, something in the debugger is trying to create a socket and that's what's blowing up.

Comment: Thanks Juanpa that was the issue...